# BindableProperty for Image Source in contentview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindable

Im trying to bind DogImage source which in my Contentview. Im trying to build reusable view objects like frame buttons. I just need to give them Image and Text from outside of contentview. Im using Images from resources folder.

this is my contentView

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PawsApp.Views.AboutMyDogViews.DogsBreedPicker"
             BindingContext="{Binding .}">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="breedStack"  Margin="30,2,30,2">
            <Frame  HeightRequest="64" CornerRadius="8" BorderColor="White" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="White" 
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="18,0,18,0">
                <Frame.Content>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Grid ColumnSpacing="18">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image x:Name="DogImage" Source="{Binding ImageSourceOf}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ></Image>
                            <Label  x:Name="breedSelector" Text="Breed" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#5f5d70" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame.Content>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And this is CS file

```
public partial class DogsBreedPicker : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ImageSourceOf", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(DogsBreedPicker));

    public ImageSource ImageSourceOf
    {
        get { return GetValue(ImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);}           
    }

    public DogsBreedPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = ImageSourceOf;
    }
}
```

And this is how i want to use it.

```
<views:DogsBreedPicker ImageSourceOf="dog" TextOf="Breed Selector" x:Name="DogBreed" ></views:DogsBreedPicker>
```

Comment: On the first glance this looks good (I'd rename `ImageSourceOf` to `ImageSource` or `ImageSourceProperty` to `ImageSourceOfProperty`, to follow the usual naming conventions, though), what exactly is your issue?

Comment: @PaulKertscher BindingContext = ImageSourceOf; always null :(

Comment: I see. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your `BindingContext` to `ImageSourceOf` in your constructor. Anyway, the properties are not set at this moment, hence `ImageSourceOf` is still `null`. However, you do not need to use `BindingContext` in this case anyway, since you can directly bind to the `ImageSourceOf` property:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PawsApp.Views.AboutMyDogViews.DogsBreedPicker"
             x:Name="View">
      <!-- Elided all the other stuff -->
      <Image x:Name="DogImage" Source="{Binding ImageSourceOf, Source={x:Reference View}}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />

</ContentView>
```

remove the assignment of `BindingContext` from your constructor.

#### Why does this work?

The default source of all bindings is the `BindingContext` (of the view, which is propagated to all child views). Anyway, you are by no means restricted to the `BindingContext` as the source of a binding, but can set the `Source` of the binding to another object. In this case we are referencing the view (which we have given the name `View` with `x:Name="View"`) by its name and use it as the source of the binding of the `Source` of the `Image`. Since the `Path` of the binding is `ImageSourceOf`, the `Image.Source` will be bound to `View.ImageSourceOf`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, thats opend my mind and make it clear.
I just remove bindingcontext and give it from view reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Content.BindingContext = this;
```

Solved my issue. But is there any way to make it better? Add comment please.

Comment: I'm just writing an answer, hold on.